# retina.js console log error for non-retina images

Tags: console, retina.js

I am using retina.js - http://retinajs.com/ and it's great however I have some images which aren't use @2x the size. On a retina screen there is obviously a console error trying the get the images which doesn't exists.

It says `GET http://...nonretinaimage@2x.png 403 (Forbidden)`

Is there a way to modify the js file to only get @2x size the image if they exist?

I am using this retina.js version to suit my images that are hosted on Amazons3 - 
https://github.com/chrishunt/retinajs/blob/master/src/retina.js

Comment: Hi no not yet, will keep you posted if i do